# Pandas - write_frame to sqlite - datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to query data from a postgresql db and insert it into an sqlite db.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as pd_sql
import sqlite3 as sql3
import psycopg2

#Aquire Data FROM PostgreSQL DB
conn_pg = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xx' user='xxxxx' host=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx password='xxxx'");
sql_1='SELECT * FROM table1 limit 5'
df_1=pd_sql.read_frame(sql_1,conn_pg)
conn_pg.close()

#Insert Into sqlite3 DB
conn_sqlite=sql3.connect('/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/my_db.db')
pd_sql.write_frame(df_1,'table1',conn_sqlite,'sqlite',if_exists='replace')
conn_sqlite.close()
```

df_1 has dtypes:
field1  object
field2  datetime64[ns]
field3  float64
field4  object
dtype: object

I am getting an error:

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

on:

```
pd_sql.write_frame(df_1,'table1',conn_sqlite,'sqlite',if_exists='replace')
```

I am guessing sqlite does not like the datetime64 of field2. I need help to figure out:
1. Which date type I should convert field2 to in my dataframe and
2. How to do this in a pandas DataFrame

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You are indeed correct that the datetime64 field is causing the troubles. Sqlite has no real datetime type, but they use text or integer types to represent times (see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

So dependent on what you want to do, you can first convert your datetime column to a string:

```
df['field2'] = df['field2'].apply(str)
```

or to an int (the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC):

```
df['field2'] = df['field2'].astype('int64')
```

and then write your data to sqlite.

---

Sidenotes:

- What version of pandas are you using? Because in version 0.13 (or below) there is a bug in the `if_exists='replace'` implementation, which is fixed in 0.13.1 (latest stable release at the moment)
- In the upcoming pandas 0.14, there will be a new implementation of the sql functions based on sqlalchemy, and there the conversion to a string will happen automatically (so not error anymore for datetime64 data).