# insert datetime in sqlite3 database error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqldatatypes

I have a pandas dataframe with the following data types

```
var1            object
var2        datetime64[ns]
var3             object
var4            object
var5             int64
var6            float64
```

my schema in the sqlite3 data base is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "table_name" (
"var1" TEXT,
"var2" DATETIME,
"var3" TEXT,
"var4" TEXT,
"var5" INT,
"var6" REAL
);
```

my query in python looks lite this

```
query = 'insert into first_north4 (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
values = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
cur.executemany(query, values)
```

When executing the query I get this error msg

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

This is the datetime that fails, I can't figure out why

Comment: Where is `values` being defined in your Python code?

Comment: Please show a single sublist of `values` as a starting point

Comment: As requested.  As a note, the code is fully functional. For instance if i just let all variables in the dataframe be strings it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for me (regarding date object), hopefully this will help somebody else in the future. Fully working example below in python3

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3

# est conn (creates db if not exist)
db = 'db_test.db'
conn=sqlite3.connect(db,
detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = conn.cursor()

# create table
query='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(i INT, f REAL, d DATE)'
cur.execute(query)

# some specific datatypes to dataframe
i = [4 ,2 ,44]
f=[1.23,123.2,2.2222]
d = [dt.date.today(),dt.date.today(),dt.date.today()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[i,f,d],index = ['i','f','d']).T
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(type(df['i'].values[0]))
print(type(df['f'].values[0]))
print(type(df['d'].values[0]))

# insert
query = 'insert into test (i, f, d) values (? ,?, ?)'
values = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
print(values)
cur.executemany(query, values)
conn.commit()

# test types when querying the db
query = cur.execute('SELECT * from test')
cols = [column[0] for column in query.description]
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=query.fetchall(), columns=cols)
print(data)
print(data.dtypes)
print(type(data['i'].values[0]))
print(type(data['f'].values[0]))
print(type(data['d'].values[0]))

# close conn
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [sqlite datatypes doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> 2.2. Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

One option would be to convert var2 to a string before db insert (thus preserving the DATETIME datatype in the database) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066261/pandas-write-frame-to-sqlite-datetime64ns/23077664#23077664). There are other options, and a search on this forum for "datetime64 sqlite" should provide other approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't upvote yes (new user). But i will come back and do it when I have enough rep. 
I solved the problem by just feeding the database with text and to the casting afterwards when querying the data